# How do the "choose one" chests work?

Tags: cadence-of-hyrule

There are a few chests in Cadence of Hyrule, perhaps always in dungeons but I don't remember for sure, where opening them offers you a choice of items. The first time I encountered one I was moving so fast that I didn't even see I was being offered a choice until it was too late. Another time, I had a choice between a hookshot, the Cane of Somaria, and I think a third option. I chose hookshot. Another one gave a choice between the Can of Somaria and poisoned arrows; I choice poisoned arrows.

At first I was worried that making this choice meant that the Cane would be unobtainable in my playthrough; but then I found a chest that just had the Cane in the Gerudo dungeon.

So how do these sort of items work? If I had chosen Cane from one of the "choose one" chests; would the chest in the Gerudo dungeon have had something different instead? Are there any items that it is impossible to get if you make the "wrong" choice at one of these chests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There are 4 "Pick One" chests, which show you up to 3 items from the same set of 4 between them

As you've probably noticed, Cadence of Hyrule doesn't have any restrictions on the order you do the dungeons in - each of them will contain exactly one of the "Pick One" chests.

No matter the order you find them in, the first will display 3 of the 4 items, while subsequent ones will display all the remaining items (depending on how many are left).  To use your example, if you'd picked the Cane of Somalia for the third chest, you'd find the Poisoned Arrows in the last one instead.  (This also means the third item in the second chest you'd forgotten was the Poisoned Arrows.)

There's no "wrong" choice, you will get all 4 of the items eventually.

Comment: It's also worth adding that this pool of 4 items is randomly generated, just like almost everything else in the game.